# Import excel header data in a drop down in .net

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, import

Hi I am importing a excel or a .csv file using OpenFileDialog in Visual Studio 2005.
I need to show all the headers in a list, which is supposed to be listed on a ComboBox.

e.g If I import a file which has 10 columns in it, my drop down should show me 10 values as 
1, 2, 3..........10

Please let me know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is completely different animal than Excel.

I would use the OpenXml library OR use the OleDb driver to read from the excel file.

Look here:  [Reading excel file using OLEDB Data Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511576/reading-excel-file-using-oledb-data-provider)

You will need to have the ACE driver installed, you may already have it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
// first read *.xls file into a DataTable; don't wory it is very quick.
public DataTable ReadExcelFile(string strFilePath)
{
    string sConnectionString  = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + strFilePath + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=No; IMEX=1;\"";
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
    objConn.Open();
    DataTable sdt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    // Change this part to read 1 row    
    String str = "SELECT TOP(2) * FROM [" + sdt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";
    //String str = "SELECT * FROM [" + sdt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";
    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(str, objConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    objAdapter1.Fill(dt);

    objConn.Close();
    dt.AcceptChanges();

    return dt;
}
```

Now working with DataTable

```
DataTable dt = ReadExcelFile(@"c:\\x.xlsx");
if (dt != null)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmb = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        cmb.Items.Insert(i, dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
}
```