# Pull Data from an excel sheet, based on a textbox contents

Tags: c#, excel

Okay, I'm currently writing an Audit program for the company I work for to allow us do Audits easier than our current process.

PROBLEM:

I'm struggling to get or find a way for VB to reference a stock file (Excel, can be converted to txt delimited files etc.) with a barcode(column 1), and pull a code(column 2) and the description(column 3) from it and put that data in two other text boxes.

I'm currently using a Windows Form Application, so C#.

Could someone please point me to an article or explain how to go about this?

Comment: If you are using C# then why did you include the VBA category and the vb.net category?

Comment: Apologies, it was what was suggested. Have changed it

Answer (score 0):

1. Option:
   Connect to the excel via oledb.
   [Reading excel file using OLEDB Data Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511576/reading-excel-file-using-oledb-data-provider)
2. Option:
   Convert the excel file to a txt file, and read it with StreamReader.