# Is there a way to import data from an excel sheet into a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to import data from an excel sheet into a database on SQL Server without using the bulk method? Keeping in mind that I'm creating a web application where the user uploads an excel file to the page and it proceeds to import it into an existing database.

The bulk method works using OleDbDataReader, except it copies the excel sheet and pastes it onto the database without considering the column names compatibility. Am I missing something?

Comment: SSIS - is one way to go.

Comment: --Also keeping in mind I'm using C# and asp.net

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatic-ly, or a one-time load in SSMS?  Because SSMS is a GUI for Sql Server, not a database itself.

Comment: @JNYRanger one-time load.. a web application that uploads an excel file and imports the data into an already existing database and that's it

Comment: If it's a one-time load the consumer of the database & programming language/frameworks used are irrelevant.  Just use the SQL Import/Export wizard in SSMS as @Fran posted.

Comment: All I had to do was use google: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Import-Excel-Spreadsheet-2b7ca7cf

Comment: okay I think I meant to say programmatically, the application will be used to import data into the database whenever i need to.. @JNYRanger

Comment: That's a bit too broad of a question here on SO, Tamara.  if you have a specific question regarding how you decided to go about this there's plenty of people who can help you here.  There are many, many, many ways to do it.  Personally, I would recommend using bulk methods from the `System.Data.SqlServer` namespace because they are the fastest & easiest way to do this.  Just be aware that using Excel files directly isn't the easiest to work with, and it's way easier to convert them to CSV first.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

If you are working through SSMS, use the SQL Import Export Wizard.  There's enough documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

From code you can use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class for importing into SQL databases.  If you are importing bulk records into Oracle you can use ODP.net [OracleBulkCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm#ODPNT7446).  Oracle bulk copying is only supported right now through the full ODP.net provider.  Managed ODP.net does not support bulk operations.

To read the Excel file you can use any number of libraries.
[LinqToExcel,](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel/) 
[OleDb,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511576/reading-excel-file-using-oledb-data-provider) 
[closedxml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Comment: But I meant through C# and asp.net, I want to create a web application that does this implicitly.. sorry the question wasn't clear, I edited it.

Comment: Your question still says "on SQL Server Management Studio", and the import wizard is a tool in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet namespace: [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet(v=office.15).aspx%20%22MADN%20Link)

It will let you look at the different parts of the spreadsheet as it is stored in OpenXML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format file along with bulk insert. The format file maps between table columns and the fields in the file.

Refer :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server