# SSIS: Convert xlsx to other format

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm trying to use SSIS 15.0.2000.68 to import an .xlsx file to a Sql Server table. When I try to use an Excel Source in the Data Task, it can't read the spreadsheet. I manually saved the .xlsx file to an earlier version of Excel and it worked fine.

I need to upload the xlsx file daily and I can't manually do it every day. I tried using a File Task to save as an .xls but SSIS can't read that. I also tried to save as csv or txt, and SSIS can't read them either.

I've read there's a MS redistributable package (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable) that will allow SSIS to import .xlsx files, but my manager doesn't want to install it.

Is it possible to use a script task to save it as another file type?

Comment: So what is the earlier version of excel file you used? Prior to xlsx was xls…

Comment: Yes, earlier version with .xls extension.

Comment: So you say it works with xls, and then you say it does not. You may need to be more clear about this… it either works or it does not.

Comment: No, I said it didn't work with .xlsx. I saved it as an earlier version (a version ending with .xls) and it works. Please read carefully when commenting.

Comment: As for read carefully, I did. You say it does not work with xlsx. Then you say it works with an earlier version, which you don’t specify. I asked in a comment if that was xls and you agreed. Then you you state SSIS cannot read xls - the very version you say works but now does not. « Read carefully » indeed.

Comment: Yes, it can read .xls - I said that. .xls is the earlier version of Excel. The issue is converting the .xlsx file to .xls, or .txt, or .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create an OLEDB connection inside of your SSIS package you could attempt [the top answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511576/reading-excel-file-using-oledb-data-provider), as this sounds like it may be useful for reading an .xls file. Essentially you would instantiate a new OLEDB connection inside of your script task and point it at the Excel file path, select all the data, and read it into a DataTable. You would first want to insert the appropriate columns into your DataTable, but assuming the columns do not change this should be easy to automate on a daily schedule.

After you have the data stored in the DataTable, you could pass it into a data flow task and create another file with the data as needed.

Comment: Thanks - the example in that question shows them using different drivers for .xlsx versus .xls. That's my issue. I can import .xls files (earlier version of Excel) but cannot import .xlsx file.